# TypeScript - Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}' - MongoStore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, typescript-typings, connect-mongo

I'm relatively new to TS and I've have encountered a type problem in `new MongoStore()` parameters. Typically I can reuse the Native MongoDB connection by writing `db: database` as an argument in JS, but TS shows the following error:

> Argument of type '{ db: Db; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MongoUrlOptions | MogooseConnectionOptions | NativeMongoOptions | NativeMongoPromiseOptions'.
>     Type '{ db: Db; }' is not assignable to type 'NativeMongoPromiseOptions'.
>       Property 'dbPromise' is missing in type '{ db: Db; }'.

I've tried writting `new MongoStore({ db: database } as NativeMongoOptions)`, but this doesn't help either.

[UPDATE] adding `as NativeMongoOptions` produces a diff error:

> Type '{ db: Db; }' is not assignable to type 'NativeMongoOptions'.
>     Types of property 'db' are incompatible.
>       Type 'import("/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index").Db' is not assignable to type 'import("/node_modules/@types/connect-mongo/node_modul...'.
>         Property 'authenticate' is missing in type 'Db'.

Is this a problem of my code or the TS typings?

Here below is the fragment of my code.

```
const MongoStore: connectMongo.MongoStoreFactory = connectMongo(session);
const app: express.Application = express();

enableMiddleware(app);

(async () => {
    try {
        const client: mongodb.MongoClient = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(config.dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true });
        console.log("Connected correctly to server");
        const database: mongodb.Db = client.db(config.dbName);

        app.use(session({
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            secret: "secret123",
            store: new MongoStore({
                db: database,
            }),
        }));

        app.use(router(database));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error connecting to MongoDB", error);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem, it was with the TS typings all along, the **@types/connect-mongo** uses an older version of **@types/mongodb** ^2, where I am using **@types/mongodb** ^3 in my project.

Current solution, update the **@types/connect-mongo** package dependencies to the newest (overwriting **@types/mongodb** ^2 to ^3).

Comment: Hey, you should accept this as the correct answer :-)
More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

you would need the line below in your devDependencies inside package.json

```
"@types/mongodb": "^3"
```